# multiplying a function in $H^s$ times a function taking values in $S^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

If $\phi=\phi(x)$ is a function $\phi:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{C}$ in $H^s(\mathbb{R}^d)$ then it's clear from the definition of the inner product in $H^s(\mathbb{R}^d)$,
\begin{equation}
\langle f, g\rangle_{s}=\sum_{|\alpha| \leq s}\left\langle\partial_x^\alpha f, \partial_x^\alpha g\right\rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)}
\end{equation}
that $e^{i\alpha}\phi$ is also in $H^s(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for any phase $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. However, is that the case if one allows $\alpha=\alpha(x)$ to be a (real-valued) function too? I've tried tackling this problem using the definition of $H^s(\mathbb{R}^d)$ in terms of Fourier transforms without any success: the Fourier transform of $e^{i\alpha(x)}\phi(x)$ doesn't have a nice expression in terms of the Fourier transform of $\phi(x)$, as far as I know. Ideally I would like to find a bound of the form
$$
\|e^{i\alpha(x)}\phi(x)\|_{s}\lesssim \|\phi(x)\|_{s}
$$
but I don't know if this is even true. If it helps, you can assume that $d=3$ and (if really necessary) that $s>d/2=3/2$. Any help would be much appreaciated, thank you!

Comment: What kind of regularity are you willing to assume of $\alpha$?

Comment: $\alpha(x)$ is the argument of a complex number whose real and imaginary parts are in $H^s(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Comment: That's insufficient: you can have very wild rotation when the absolute value is small still keeping the function smooth but, when scaled to size 1, it will blow up the derivatives.